# How to do CRUD (especially Update) Using Import Excel, but ONLY EXPORT ONCE for forever?

Tags: sql, algorithm, database-design, phpexcel

I want to import data from excel, so the user can bulk input.
For example:

```
Table Product:
id
name
price
```

What I need is, users only export **ONCE** to see the template, and understand how to input, and they never need to export again to add or update or delete. So they only need to import to update, import to add and import to delete, they don't need to export.

And the template what I think is:

```
id      name      price
```

The Method I think are:

For Add: Check if the id is null/empty, then add to database

For Delete: Check if the id in database not available in excel, then remove from database.

For update: *I know if we can import the file, and then user export it to get id from server and user update the data, so the server can understand what data to update, but that's not what I want, I want to export just once, and update forever, not export everytime user want to update*

What I am thinking of for update:

- Method 1. User generates the id by themself
- Method 2. Everytime user import the file, delete all data in database and
  insert all user data, but this method will break all the relation,
  and I think it's not effective.

Any other better method that can solve this problem?

Comment: "This method will break the relation" Correct. If a user can put anything they want in this table without needing to respect relations, it's guaranteed to break no matter what you do

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you want. You want a user to maintain a database table by using excel. What kind of database? MySQL? Where does PHPExcel fit into this? You should definitely generate id's in the database and you should definitely ignore any request to delete data that is referenced. Do you know VBA? This often a good option for transferring data from excel to a database.